# mysql return mix-of-collations when trying using case in selecting two different content

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two different content in **view db**, in where this **view db** is generated from **table db**.

there are two columns here from table

```
(CASE WHEN view.dcs = 8 then view.uc2content else view.utf8content END) as 'dcsContent'
```

uc2content and utf8content are surely two different encoding character, which I create to a view using this query

```
CONVERT(a.textcolA USING utf8) as utf8content,
CONVERT(a.textcolb USING ucs2) as uc2content,
```

Any idea how to get rid of this `mix-of-collations`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please create a complete and reproducible example with CREATE statements and the exact error message. Also post the server version.

Comment: this are character sets and not collations and you can't get rid of them ,. if your data is safed by in adofferent charwters set or collation, you must add it

Comment: You really must provide a test case _including how you inserted the text_.

Answer (score 1):

The result column needs to be in 1 character set for all cases. If your source columns use different character sets, convert them into one (preferably utf8bm4, or utf8 for older mysql versions).

```
(CASE WHEN view.dcs = 8 
  THEN CONVERT(view.uc2content USING utf8bm4)
  ELSE CONVERT(view.utf8content USING utf8mb4)
END) AS 'dcsContent'
```

However, I think it would be best not to convert sources to different character sets in the first place. Just store everything in utf8bm4 or utf8 in the first place, and not convert anything in select or view.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix two character sets in one column. The engine needs to know the exact data type of every column in a result set **before the query is executed**. And this includes the character set and collation. I can't even imagine how you can make any sense of that, or what you are going to do with the expected result client side. There might be another, better and simpler way to solve the real problem.

However - What you can do, is to return the values as BINARY:

```
(CASE WHEN view.dcs = 8
    then BINARY view.uc2content
    else BINARY view.utf8content
END) as 'dcsContent'
```